# The inline constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following inline constraint: 'range (1,12)'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
[Route("movies/released/{year}/{month:regex(\\d{4}):range (1,12)}")]
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: The inline constraint resolver of
>   type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the
>   following inline constraint: 'range (1,12)'.

I'm getting an error while viewing it on web.

Comment: you need an extra backslash I think: `\\d` not `\d`

Comment: There are already two backslashes \\

Comment: They were just added. Remove the space so it is `range(1,12)` not `range (1,12)` and see if it makes a difference

Comment: Yes, It is working now. Thanks. I just removed the space between range(1,12).And now it's working perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraint are case sensitive and you need to remove any white spaces.

This will work (no space): `range(1,12)`

This will NOT work (has space): `range (1,12)`